# Изменить порядок массива php

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Помогите пожалуйста с решением простой задачи.

Есть массив чисел в строгом порядке от 1:

`$array = [1,2,3,4];`

и есть например число с которого эта последовательность должна начинаться, например 3. Как получить на выходе вот такой результат?

`$array = [3,4,1,2];`

или если например 4, то последовательность:

`$array = [4,1,2,3];`

2 соответсвенно:

`$array = [2,3,4,1];`

Примечание: числа это сезоны года. Нужно от текущего сезона начинать)

Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать, создав функцию, которая будет проверять первый элемент массива на требуемую цифру, а затем последовательно сдвигать массив вправо через [`array_pop()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-pop.php) (удаляет последний элемент массива) и [`array_unshift()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unshift.php) (добавляет в начало массива некоторый элемент).

```php
<?php

function array_pop_unshift($array, $num) {
    while ($array[0] !== $num) {
        array_unshift($array, array_pop($array));
    }
    return $array;
}

$array = [1,2,3,4];
$new = array_pop_unshift($array, 4);
print_r($new);
```

Comment: 3 часа искал решение, не выдержал, написал. То что нужно! Спасибо Вам огромное!

Answer (score 0):

я вас, наверное, удивлю, но для 4х сезонов решение будет простым как валенок, и не надо его усложнять:

```
$seasons = [
     1 => [1,2,3,4],
     2 => [2,3,4,1],
     3 => [3,4,1,2],
     4 => [4,1,2,3],     
  ];
print_r($seasons[$needle]);
```

Comment: Надо немного отдохнуть видимо. Проще некуда. Спасибо большое! Только решение выше подойдет тем у кого количество элементов больше 4)

Comment: @Skynet технически оно подойдёт вообще всем массивам, не только тем, у которых более 4 элементов :)

Answer (score 0):

Более короткий вариант решения:

```
<?php
print_r(array_slice([1,2,3,4,1,2,3], $num - 1, 4));
```